# Method for finding which symfony package is not compatible with another symfony version

Tags: php, symfony, package, updates

I would like know if there is a method for detecting compatibility of symfony packages for symfony version?

I would like to upgrade symfony from 2.8 to 3.4.

Example: if sonata/userbundle is compatible with symfony 3.4.

Comment: you can look at the composer.json file for any package, and you'll see the minimum requirements; also the requirements should be listed in detail in the respective sites for the packages; and last but not least: composer (https://getcomposer.org/) was created for this.

Comment: I ask this because i have some problem to update symfony from 2.8 to 3.4, thank's for your comment

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading major versions follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html) guide,

for specific incompatibilities and replacements look at [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-3.0.md) page.

Most of the work is handled by composer, but you will still need to replace deprecated functions and approaches.